# Count points in polygon tool keeps failing in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I keep getting an error and when i check the logs this is what I'm seeing. All layers are using the same CRS, I've tried v.clean just in case. I'm stumped.

> Uncaught error while executing algorithm          Traceback (most recent
>   call last):
>               File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\GeoAlgorithm.py",
>   line 203, in execute
>                 self.processAlgorithm(progress)
>               File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\PointsInPolygon.py",
>   line 80, in processAlgorithm
>                 spatialIndex = vector.spatialindex(pointLayer)
>               File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\vector.py",
>   line 220, in spatialindex
>                 idx = QgsSpatialIndex(layer.getFeatures(request))           Exception: unknown

Comment: Can you provide test data to reproduce this issue? As this question stands, there is not much to go on.